# Why I am having SQFlite data to be typecasted with toString() explicitly?

Tags: flutter

I am fetching the data through SQFlite. Why is it that I have to explicitly typecast my output as string `'${cardUser.firstname.toString().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()}',` whereas throughout in the class I'm using String declarations. If I remove this `toString()`, it gives me a `NoSuchMethodError`. 
However, in ListView title and subtitle, it is displaying the data fine.

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The method 'substring' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: substring(0, 1)
```

```
class User {
  int _id;
  String _firstname;
  String _lastname;

  User(this._firstname, this._lastname);

  String get lastname => _lastname;
  String get firstname => _firstname;
  int get id => _id;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
    map['firstname'] = firstname;
    map['lastname'] = lastname;
    if(id != null){
      map['id'] = id;
    }
    return map;
  }

  User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    this._id = map['id'];
    this._firstname = map['firstname'];
    this._lastname = map['lastname'];
  }

  // works similar to fromMap but its here
  // to handled _linkedInternalHashMap or other objects
  User.map(dynamic obj) {
    this._id = obj['id'];
    this._firstname = obj['firstname'];
    this._lastname = obj['lastname'];
  }

}
```

**Usage**

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Database'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _users.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, position) {
              User cardUser = User.fromMap(_users[position]);
              return Card(
                elevation: 8.0,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                      child: Text(
                    '${cardUser.firstname.toString().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  )),
                  title: Text('${cardUser.firstname} ${cardUser.lastname}'),
                  subtitle: Text('Id: ${cardUser.id}'),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

```
flutter doctor -v output (just incase)
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.17.0 at D:\flutter-sdk
    • Framework revision e6b34c2b5c (3 weeks ago), 2020-05-02 11:39:18 -0700
    • Engine revision 540786dd51
    • Dart version 2.8.1
```

Comment: Try to know it's type then..like..keep a dummy `IconButton` in `AppBar`'s `actions` part..and try to print it's `runtimeType`.. something like.. ```onPressed:(){print(cardUser.firstname.runtimeType);}``` that will give some idea on how to proceed further..just give it a try..say what it gives you..

Comment: Finally figured out. There was a null entry in the table. Fixed it like this.
```if(cardUser.firstname == null) return Container(height: 0, width: 0,);```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out. There was a null entry in the table. Fixed it like this. `if(cardUser.firstname == null) return Container(height: 0, width: 0,);` changed the code like this.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Database'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _users.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, position) {
              User cardUser = User.fromMap(_users[position]);
              if(cardUser.firstname == null) return Container(height: 0, width: 0,);
              return Card(
                elevation: 8.0,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                      child: Text(
                    '${cardUser.firstname.toString().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  )),
                  title: Text('${cardUser.firstname} ${cardUser.lastname}'),
                  subtitle: Text('Id: ${cardUser.id}'),
                  onTap: (){print(cardUser.firstname.runtimeType);},
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```